# Join using times to result in multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a fairly tricky situation (at least to me). I'm trying to write a SQL statement that will take an event table which looks like:

```
Event   HourId      Start                  End
Event1  1203170200  3/17/2012 02:30:00 PM  3/17/2012 04:15:00 PM
```

And join with a calendar table that looks like

```
HourId      Start                  End
1203170200  3/17/2012 02:00:00 PM  3/17/2012 02:59:59 PM  
1203170300  3/17/2012 03:00:00 PM  3/17/2012 03:59:59 PM  
1203170400  3/17/2012 04:00:00 PM  3/17/2012 04:59:59 PM  
1203170500  3/17/2012 05:00:00 PM  3/17/2012 05:59:59 PM
```

And I want the result to be a record for each of the hours that the event spans:

```
Event   HourId      Start                  End
Event1  1203170200  3/17/2012 02:30:00 PM  3/17/2012 04:15:00 PM
Event1  1203170300  3/17/2012 02:30:00 PM  3/17/2012 04:15:00 PM
Event1  1203170400  3/17/2012 02:30:00 PM  3/17/2012 04:15:00 PM
```

A list of the hours alone does not suffice, I've been able to get that far.  I need to get the result in the above format for use in another algorithm.  Can anyone suggest some SQL that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  e.Event,
  c.HourId,
  e."Start",
  e."End"
FROM Events e
  INNER JOIN Calendar c ON c."Start" <= e."End"
                       AND e."Start" <= c."End"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.Event,T1.HourId,T1.Start,T1.End
FROM Table1 T1,Table2 T2
WHERE T1.HourId=T2.HourID;
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work. It does not account for all of the hours in the timespan?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    e.event,
    c.hourid,
    e.start,
    e.end
from event e
inner join calendar c on 
    e.start between c.start and c.end 
    or 
    e.end between c.start and c.end
    or
    trunc(e.start, 'hour') <= trunc(c.start, 'hour') 
    and 
    trunc(e.end, 'hour') >= trunc(c.end, 'hour')
order by c.hourid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ee.event,cc.hourId,ee.start,ee.end
from calend cc 
join event ee on (cc.Start between ee.Start and ee.end) or 
                 (cc.EndD between ee.Start and ee.End)
```

Comment: Close but it doesn't catch all cases.